# How to respond to "help" on Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I got the following feedback from Google team:

*When a user says "help" to your agent, it does not actually provide any guidance for what a user can say or ask for, it just says "sure, assistants are here to help"*

My webhook is implemented in Spring Boot. Any idea how my web service can respond to help requests?

Comment: Are you using API.AI with webhooks, or Actions to your webhooks directly?

Comment: I am using API.AI for building actions. The webhook points to a REST web service that I have deployed on Heroku using Spring Boot Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using API.AI, that sounds like it might be one of the default responses that are built-in to the Small Talk Domain. You'll probably want to do two things:

1. Turn off the Small Talk Domain by clicking on the *Domains* menu on the left and then turning the switch on the *Small Talk* domain (it should be the first one) off.
2. Make your own Intent to handle the "help" command (and possibly a few other related statements) by setting these in the *User Says* section of the Intent. You can have this intent fulfilled by sending it to your webhook by checking the *Use Webhook* box in the *Fulfillment* section, but for simple text responses this probably isn't necessary. Just have the Intent return a short help message describing what can be done by adding text to the *Response* area.

Some suggestions and things to consider when writing your help intent or intents:

- Make the response relatively short. This is text that, when read, can't be interrupted.
- Consider context-sensitive help by using *Input Contexts* to determine the state of the conversation at that moment. A user asking for help after a particular prompt should get information that helps them at that prompt.
- Allow for multiple ways to ask for help in the *User Says* section. Phrases like "I'm confused" may also be good to trigger help.
- Allow for asking for help on specific topics by using multiple intents that provide different answers. These may be tied to the Contexts as well.